# if statement for Tinymce plugin justboil.me

Tags: php, tinymce, justboil.me

I will try and explain this best as possible.

I am using the TinyMCE editor with the plugin from justboil.me called jbimages for my image compression and resizing.

I'm using TinyMCE for two parts of my website. A Blog page and a Classifieds page.

When I upload my images I want the blog images to go in the blog image folder and the classified images to go into the classified image folder.

The jbimage plugin uses a config.php file that asks for a Path to upload target folder. Like this:

```
$config['img_path'] = '/image_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

How can I add a statement that would allow me to send images to my blog images folder when I'm using TinyMCE on my blog page and another statement that would allow me to send images to my classifieds images folder when I'm using TinyMCE on my classifieds page?

I tried using an include function to the above code on the blog upload page and classifieds upload page and removed the above code in the config.php file in hopes that when the browser reads the page it would work, but it did not.

What I'm looking for is something like this.

- If blog page use the blog image path
- If classifieds page use the classifieds image path

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have the images going to a file folder now but they are both going into my NoticesImages folder for some reason.

At the top of my notices page I have the following:

```
<?php
$title = 'Admin';
$page_description = "Add description in here.";
$thisPage="notices";
include_once "../adminheader.php";
?>
```

At the top of my classifieds page I have the following:

```
<?php
$title = 'Admin';
$page_description = "Add description in here.";
$thisPage="classifieds";
include_once "../adminheader.php";
?>
```

Then in my config.php file I changed it to this:

```
if($thisPage="notices"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/NoticesImages'; // Relative to domain name
} else if($thisPage="classifieds"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages'; // Relative to domain name
} else {

}
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

Now my problem is when I upload to from classifieds page the image goes into the NoticesImages folder instead of the ClassifiedsImages folder.

**What do I need to change in my config.php statement to correct this problem?**

---

**UPDATE:2**

I recently tried this: But images just fall to the root of the website.

```
if($thisPage=="notices"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/NoticesImages'; 
} elseif($thisPage=="classifieds"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages'; 
} else {
}
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path'];
```

Ive tried this: Files go to the notices folder on both..?

```
if($thisPage>="notices"){
        $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/NoticesImages'; 
    } elseif($thisPage>="classifieds"){
        $config['img_path'] = '/knolls_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages';
```

I've tried ==, ===, >= and <= and nothing seems to allow the notices images to go to the notices folder and the classified images to go to the classifieds folder.

Been working on this for almost 2 days know. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. The problem here is your if statement, it's setting the variable $thisPage to "notices", not checking if it is equal to "notices". You're missing an = sign.

if($thisPage = "notices"){ should be if($thisPage == "notices"){ or even if($thisPage === "notices"){

Comment: @i-CONICA Would same go for the classifies?

Comment: @i-CONICA See Update 2 at top.

Comment: You can print out the contents of $thisPage with print_r($thisPage, true);  it'll show you the contents of the variable so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways, but the most preferable is to set a constant in the run of the blog, and in the run of the classifieds, and check that.

```
if(BLOG_OR_CLSSFDS === "blog"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/image_file_manager/source/BlogImages'; // Relative to domain name
} elseif(BLOG_OR_CLSSFDS === "classifieds"){
    $config['img_path'] = '/image_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages'; // Relative to domain name
} else {
    //you might want to throw an error or set a default.
}
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]

// or

if(isset($_GET['blog_page_id'])){
    $config['img_path'] = '/image_file_manager/source/BlogImages'; // Relative to domain name
} elseif(isset($_GET['classifieds_page_id'])){
    $config['img_path'] = '/image_file_manager/source/ClassifiedsImages'; // Relative to domain name
} else {
    //you might want to throw an error or set a default.
}
```

Or you could have a hidden form field with a value to denote which.

Comment: Could you tell me how to set a constant on my blog page?

Comment: define("BLOG_OR_CLASSFDS", "blog");

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

It just needs to be defined above the call to it, so if your system hits an "index.php" and everything runs through there, at some point, the switch between it being a blog or classifieds page would be a good place to define that distinction. Or if the system for blogs and system for classifieds are two separate entities, then just set one to "blog" and one to "classifieds" at the top of the script.

Comment: Still cant seem to get it working. On my classifieds.php page I have this at the top of the page.

`<?php
$title = 'Admin';
$page_description = "Add description before publishing.";
$thisPage="classifieds";
define('NOTICES_OR_CLSSFDS', 'classifieds');
include_once "../adminheader.php";
?>`

and using the first method you mentioned. Images upload, but to the root of the website. 


Do you see something I'm doing wrong here? Also tried 2nd method, but didnt seem to work.

Comment: FYI BLOG = Notices, I just wrote blog for sake of making things easier to understand.

Comment: If they upload to the root, it'd imply the var wasn't set. It seems you've already got $thisPage set.

Comment: I use $thisPage for my navigation to set it in an active state. Is there a way I could use  $thisPage in the config file? Sorry  I've just been learning PHP by the seat of my pants. I realize I need to learn the fundamentals, just really need to get this working.

Comment: please see update at top of page. Close to getting it working.